# getSymbols not returning data as expected

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm having some trouble getting equity pricing data into R. I have a list of over 4k symbols, and some are no longer active/ valid. I was using an lapply with get.hist.quote on the list, but some bad tickers stopped it in its tracks too much for it to be a practical approach. Following this post: [l_ply: how to pass the list's name attribute into the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548263/l-ply-how-to-pass-the-lists-name-attribute-into-the-function) and attempting to use the accepted answer is the seemingly best approach I can find, but it isn't working. The l_ply doesn't load any symbols into my workspace. I get these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 90279 != reported length 200
2: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 87827 != reported length 200
3: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 89737 != reported length 200
```

The code from the post cited above that I'm trying to use is below. Is there a fix to this? I'm seeing other postings regarding similar situations, but fixes such as this one aren't working for me. If anyone else has a good way for me to get daily data on many tickers, I'm open to all suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)
symbols <- c("MSFT","C","MMM")

#1
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym))) 
symbols <- symbols[symbols %in% ls()]

#2
sym.list <- llply(symbols, get) 

#3
data <- xts()
for(i in seq_along(symbols)) {
  symbol <- symbols[i]
  data <- merge(data, get(symbol)[,paste(symbol, "Close", sep=".")])
}
```

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors.  But, you say "not returning data as expected."  What was expected and how is it different than what you got?

Comment: Poor wording; yes, warnings. I was expecting symbols with data in my workspace; but, I have none.

Comment: Oh I see.  If you used `getSymbols(sym, env=globalenv())` it'd do what you expected.  I'll add an answer with the more common idiom

Comment: a couple related posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179154/r-names-of-quantmod-variables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574595/getsymbols-and-using-lapply-cl-and-merge-to-extract-close-prices?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that by default `getSymbols` assigns the data in the `parent.frame()`.  When you call `getSymbols()` from a function, the `parent.frame()` is no longer the `.GlobalEnv` that you're used to.  So, a quick fix to your current could would be to replace

```
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym)))
```

with

```
l_ply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym, env=globalenv())))
```

Note that you may run into trouble at the next step where you use `get`.  You should probably also specify which environment you want to `get` the data from so that it would also work if you put it in a function.  i.e. `sym.list <- llply(symbols, get, pos=globalenv())`

---

Here's a more common idiom for getting and merging data with quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
s <- c("MSFT","C","MMM")
e <- new.env() #environment in which to store data
getSymbols(s, src="yahoo", env=e)
do.call(merge, eapply(e, Cl)[s])
```

Or, using `try` like the OP

```
L <- lapply(symbols, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym, auto.assign=FALSE)))
do.call(merge, lapply(L, Cl))
```